# Determine if file type is ASCII text in bash

Tags: bash, ascii, file-type

I have to sort and print all the file names of files that are ASCII text from a given folder.
I made this so far but the file names are printed even if they are PNG images.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $1/*
do
nume=$(basename $f)

if [ 'file $nume'=="$1/$nume: ASCII text" ]; then
    echo $nume
fi
done
```

Can someone please explain what`s wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you understand why `$(...)` is used to run `basename`? The same reason applies to running `file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `[` wants just an equal sign, not two, and it needs to be separated by spaces (see `help test`):

   ```
   [ 'file $nume' = "$1/$nume: ASCII text" ]
   ```
2. You need `$(...)` to get the output from a command:

   ```
   [ "$(file $nume)" = "$1/$nume: ASCII text" ]
   ```
3. Why are you using `basename`? `file` is not going to find your file if you don't give it the whole path:

   ```
   for f in $1/*
   do
       if [ "$(file $f)" = "$f: ASCII text" ]; then
           echo $f
       fi
   done
   ```
4. Always quote your expansions. Quoting can save you a lot of headaches:

   ```
   for f in "$1"/*
   do
       if [ "$(file "$f")" = "$f: ASCII text" ]; then
           echo "$f"
       fi
   done
   ```
5. *(Optional)* Personally, I'd take advantage of `[[` and regex matching:

   ```
   if [[ "$(file "$f")" =~ ': ASCII text'$ ]]; then
   ```

Comment: 6. I'd take advantage of `case $(file "$f") in *text) echo matched text ;; *) echo no match on text ;; esac` ; -) Note that even with a fileName containing spaces, you only need to dbl-quote "$f", not the whole output of `$(file "$f")` . Good luck to all.

Comment: `file -b` will remove the file name from the resulting text.  Works on Fedora 27 and MacOS 10.13.